# Python: Extract a tuple from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, extract

```
print(NGramLM.ngram_counts)
```

So, `(NGramLM.ngram_counts)` returns me this

```
Counter({('Natural-language', ('<s>', '<s>')): 1, ('processing', ('<s>', 'Natural-language')): 1, ('processing', ('Natural-language', 'processing')): 1, ('is', ('processing', 'processing')): 1, ('an', ('processing', 'is')): 1, ('area', ('is', 'an')): 1, ('is', ('an', 'area')): 1, ('an', ('area', 'is')): 1, ('of', ('is', 'an')): 1, ('Natural-language', ('an', 'of')): 1, ('processing', ('of', 'Natural-language')): 1, ('(NLP)', ('Natural-language', 'processing')): 1, ('</s>', ('processing', '(NLP)')): 1, ('</s>', ('(NLP)', '</s>')): 1})
```

I need to extract every tuple inside the tuple and insert it into the list

When I do this,

```
context_list = ([x[1] for x in NGramLM.ngram_counts])
print(context_list)
```

I get this

```
[('<s>', '<s>'), ('<s>', 'Natural-language'), ('Natural-language', 'processing'), ('processing', '(NLP)'), ('(NLP)', 'is'), ('is', 'an'), ('an', 'area'), ('area', 'is'), ('is', 'an'), ('an', 'of'), ('of', 'Natural-language'), ('processing', '(NLP)'), ('(NLP)', '</s>')]
```

But `('Natural-language', 'processing')` appears only once, it is supposed to display twice in `context_list`. I don't know why it's happening!

Output I expect: (Check the third last tuple)

```
  [('<s>', '<s>'), ('<s>', 'Natural-language'), ('Natural-language', 'processing'), ('processing', '(NLP)'), ('(NLP)', 'is'), ('is', 'an'), ('an', 'area'), ('area', 'is'), ('is', 'an'), ('an', 'of'), ('of', 'Natural-language'), ('Natural-language', 'processing'),('processing', '(NLP)'), ('(NLP)', '</s>')]
```

Comment: Could you add the output you DO expect to help make the question clearer?

Comment: No, `('processing', ('Natural-language', 'processing'))` appears once and `('(NLP)', ('Natural-language', 'processing'))` appears once. These are difference tuples with common sub-tuples. It appears somebody is trying to count the frequency of tuples. The result will be dictionary with each unique tuple as the key and the number of occurrences of that tuple as the value.

Comment: Each key is a tuple that contains tuples, do you only want the *inner* tuples of each key??

Comment: Also `([x[1] for x in NGramLM.ngram_counts])` is a generator expression. How is it when you print it you get a list and not a generator object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `elements()` method of the `Counter` object to obtain the desired list with items repeated according to their counts:

```
context_list = [x for _, x in NGramLM.ngram_counts.elements()]
```